# top five delay time with log file with shell script

Tags: text-processing, sort

Input file

```
Mar 19 06:10:16 ip-172-2-0-53 sendmail[28131]: v2JDA1k4028131: to=root, ctladdr=root (0/0), delay=00:00:15, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=30580, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (v2JDAG5W028134 Message accepted for delivery)
Mar 19 14:41:26 ip-172-2-0-53 sendmail[29483]: v2JLfNFN029481: to=<xyz@ifaded.com>,<abc@ifaded.com>, delay=00:00:03, xdelay=00:00:03, mailer=esmtp, pri=151738, relay=ifaded-com.mail.p...ction.outlook.com. [xx.xxx.x.x], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (<ssssa@heg.jkadionbub.com> [InternalId=31288836753166, Hostname=ERGsDGddssdD5.namprd07.prod.outlook.com] 8924 bytes in 0.309, 28.142 KB/sec Queued mail for delivery)
Mar 19 06:10:26 ip-172-2-0-53 sendmail[28131]: v2JDA1k4028131: to=root, ctladdr=root (0/0), delay=00:20:15, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=30580, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (v2JDAG5W028134 Message accepted for delivery)
```

I have tried following command

```
 cat logh.txt | grep -E -o " delay=.[^,]*|^[^ip]+"
```

i want to find out top 5 delay time  with date how can i solve this problem with llinux command.
i am getting following output

```
Mar 19 06:10:16
 delay=00:00:15
Mar 19 14:41:26
 delay=00:00:03
Mar 19 06:10:26
 delay=00:20:15
```

Desired output

```
  Mar 19 06:10:26 delay=00:20:15
  Mar 19 06:10:16 delay=00:00:15
  Mar 19 14:41:26 delay=00:00:03
```

Comment: Are the two prepended spaces in your desired output deliberate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going to need multiple passes. Here's a solution that uses `sed`, `sort`, `head` and `cut` to give you the top 5 in the order you want.

```
sed -e 's/^\([A-Za-z]\{3\} \{1,2\}[0-9]\{1,2\} \{1,2\}\([0-9]\{2\}:\)\{2\}[0-9]\{2\}\).* \(delay=\([0-9]\{2\}\):\([0-9]\{2\}\):\([0-9]\{2\}\)\).*/\4\5\6 \1 \3/' | sort -nr | head -n5 | cut -d\  -f2-
```

With your provided input, this emits:

```
Mar 19 06:10:26 delay=00:20:15
Mar 19 06:10:16 delay=00:00:15
Mar 19 14:41:26 delay=00:00:03
```

(Assumes its input is in the log format you provided, and that it's only fed lines with the data you want. An additional grep at the beginning may be necessary.)

## What it's doing

Let's break it down.

### sed

`sed` stands for Stream EDitor. It's routinely used for applying regular expressions to text streams.

### sed's regular expression

```
's/^\([A-Za-z]\{3\} \{1,2\}[0-9]\{1,2\} \{1,2\}\([0-9]\{2\}:\)\{2\}[0-9]\{2\}\).* \(delay=\([0-9]\{2\}\):\([0-9]\{2\}\):\([0-9]\{2\}\)\).*/\4\5\6 \1 \3/'
```

That's quite the mouthful, but it rather needs to be, in order to avoid [catastrophic backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html).

We're using Regex substitutions. To see what it's doing in detail, [try Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/FH9HFb/1). For now, know that it takes the input:

```
Mar 19 06:10:16 ip-172-2-0-53 sendmail[28131]: v2JDA1k4028131: to=root, ctladdr=root (0/0), delay=00:00:15, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=30580, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (v2JDAG5W028134 Message accepted for delivery)
Mar 19 14:41:26 ip-172-2-0-53 sendmail[29483]: v2JLfNFN029481: to=<jdoe@ifaded.com>,<ksmith@ifaded.com>, delay=00:00:03, xdelay=00:00:03, mailer=esmtp, pri=151738, relay=ifaded-com.mail.p...ction.outlook.com. [xx.xxx.x.x], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (<4253fa32d79a11ce3b5f5147278dfae9@heg.jkadionbub.com> [InternalId=31288836753166, Hostname=FOOBAR1.namprd07.prod.outlook.com] 8924 bytes in 0.309, 28.142 KB/sec Queued mail for delivery)
Mar 19 06:10:26 ip-172-2-0-53 sendmail[28131]: v2JDA1k4028131: to=root, ctladdr=root (0/0), delay=00:20:15, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=30580, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (v2JDAG5W028134 Message accepted for delivery)
```

and converts it to

```
000015 Mar 19 06:10:16 delay=00:00:15
000003 Mar 19 14:41:26 delay=00:00:03
002015 Mar 19 06:10:26 delay=00:20:15
```

### sed regex match

```
^\([A-Za-z]\{3\} \{1,2\}[0-9]\{1,2\} \{1,2\}\([0-9]\{2\}:\)\{2\}[0-9]\{2\}\).* \(delay=\([0-9]\{2\}\):\([0-9]\{2\}\):\([0-9]\{2\}\)\).*
```

We first explicitly match the date components; we'll need those for output, later. We then find and match the delay and its timing components individually; the delay, you wanted in your output. The timing components, we'll need later, for sorting.

### sed's regex substitution

```
\4\5\6 \1 \3
```

In the substitution side of the regex, we take the timing components we grabbed, and we concatenate them without the ":" delimeter they originally had. This is important, as we're going to use these for `sort` later. After the timing components, we append the date string and the whole, original delay string; we'll want them after we sort.

### sort

```
sort -nr
```

Since our input now begins with a decimal number instead of a stringy time stamp, we can use `sort`'s numeric mode, specified with the `-n` flag.

By default, `sort` sorts in ascending order, which places the largest values at the end. Since this would mean processing *all* of `sort`'s output to find the largest N values, we use sort's `-r` flag to reverse the output order; now, the largest values will be output first, and we can `head` instead of `tail.

Our output, at this point, looks like this:

```
002015 Mar 19 06:10:26 delay=00:20:15
000015 Mar 19 06:10:16 delay=00:00:15
000003 Mar 19 14:41:26 delay=00:00:03
```

### head

```
head -n5
```

At this point, our input will have the largest values first, and we already know we want the largest 5 values. So we use `head`'s `-n` parameter to tell `head` how many values we want.

Since, in this example, we don't actually have more than 5 values, we still get all of the output we were fed in.

```
002015 Mar 19 06:10:26 delay=00:20:15
000015 Mar 19 06:10:16 delay=00:00:15
000003 Mar 19 14:41:26 delay=00:00:03
```

### cut

```
cut -d\  -f2-
```

Since we don't need it any more, we need to strip out the numeric sorting key we inserted with `sed` back in the first step. For this, we turn to `cut`, which allows us to choose which fields we want from each row provided.

We use cut's `-d` parameter to tell it what our field separator, our delimiter, is. Because the field separator is whitespace, we need to escape it with `\`, giving us `-d\`.

From `cut`'s perspective, this breaks the row `002015 Mar 19 06:10:26 delay=00:20:15`into `002015` `Mar` `19` `06:10:26` `delay=00:20:15`.

To specify which fields we want, we use `-f`. Since we want all but the first field, we use `-f2-`, giving us our desired output:

```
Mar 19 06:10:26 delay=00:20:15
Mar 19 06:10:16 delay=00:00:15
Mar 19 14:41:26 delay=00:00:03
```

Comment: working great...

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -lane '
   print join $", /\sdelay=\K(\S+)(?=,)/, splice(@F, 0, 3), /\s\K(delay=\S+)(?=,)/;
' | sort -t: -k 1,1nr -k 2,2nr -k 3,3nr | cut -d\  -f2- | head -n 5
```